# Css body width changes between desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

I've been having problems with having my pages use 100% width. It works fine on desktop, taking the full page width, but on mobile it gets weird. I am using NextJS, and Material-UI, if it makes any difference. I tried to set width: 100%, but it doesn't change anything.

My CSS is:

global.css:

```
    html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

_app.js

```
<Head>
        <title>E-commerce</title>
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"
                                />
        </Head>
```

This is the body width on mobile. The HTML, body width is the gray part

[image: This is the body width on mobile]

Comment: Please add all neccessary code (HTML, CSS, JS) in a runnable snippet so we can see whats going on. How? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. As of what youve posted we cant see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need but try using `width: 100vw`. That might do the job. Although you should try to avoid giving width to `<body>` and use a container `<div>` instead.
 From the image it looks like your body content is overflowing from the body tag which would later cause problems as your project expands and has more elements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the CSS you pasted is the only style you have, The preview is as expected. Please add @media queries to your CSS. Also add "box-sizing" to your **HTML** and **body** tags.

```css
html, body, *{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Your CSS is working fine for desktop view. But in the `<body>` tag you have some element(s) that are bigger than the current viewport. Use the browser developer tool and you'll find the element(s).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).